# ImageIO when reading GIF image throws IndexOutOfBoundsException: off < 0 || len < 0 || off+len > b.length || off+len < 0

Tags: java, gif, javax.imageio

When reading some GIF images using ImageIO library, I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: off < 0 || len < 0 || off+len > b.length || off+len < 0!
 at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.read(FileCacheImageInputStream.java:157)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.getCode(GIFImageReader.java:306)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(GIFImageReader.java:909)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
 ...
```

It seems like internal bug GifImageReader. Is there way to resolve this? Code is running under Java 6.

**EDIT:**
after some debugging i found, that problem is not in reading gif image, but writing it.

my (reduced) code for writing image:

```
// Buffered image, using Scalr for resize it
BufferedImage resizedImage = Scalr.resize(image, Method.AUTOMATIC, resizeMode, maxWidth, maxHeight);

ByteArrayOutputStream tmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "gif", tmp);
return new ByteArrayInputStream(tmp.toByteArray());
// then converted into blob and persisted into Oracle DB
```

When I look into blob in database using Oracle SQL Developer, data as text contains large (i.e ~4MB) binary data beginning with:

```
GIF89a ÷ %*4?40<B=JCEDKDSF:KLKDLTLL
```

In same tool (OSD) when i try to view it as image, it only print me same string (why???):

```
off < 0 || len < 0 || off+len > b.length || off+len < 0
```

It happens only for some GIF of files. It seems that all of them were converted from another format (JPG, PNG). So files are probably messed up, but this low level exception when reading cause me troubles. Because when writing image into blob, everything seems ok and I am getting exception only while reading it.

For reading (when exception is thrown) the code is simple:

```
byte[] imageData = ...  
ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inStream); // IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces this exception

Comment: Hi alan, question was extended.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? It seems to me that the version you are using is writing corrupted GIF files. The reason OSD displays the same error message, is probably that it is a Java application too, so you actually get the same exception. Try dumping the contents of the blob to disk, and try opening in a native tool, to verify that the files are indeed corrupt. If this is the case, maybe the easiest fix would be to just use PNG format instead?